# Zend: Problems defining select option with NULL value for submission to INT MySQL field

Tags: zend-framework

I have a database field defined as INT with NULL Allowed. The data submitted to this field is produced by a select form element whos values are defined using addMultiOption and addMultiOptions in combination e.g.

```
$selectData = $dataModel->getPairs();
$updateForm->getElement('type_id')->addMultiOption(NULL, '- Not Selected -');
$updateForm->getElement('type_id')->addMultiOptions($selectData);
```

The problem is that the NULL I'm trying to assign to the "- Not Selected -" option is being converted to an empty string at some point and MySQL is throwing an error because an empty string is an incorrect integer value.

How can I modify this such that the NULL arrives at the MySQL insert as a NULL?

Regards,

Nick

EDIT: See Daniel Gadawski's answer below. Below is the final result.

```
$selectData = $dataModel->getPairs();
$updateForm->getElement('type_id')->addFilter(new Zend_Filter_Null());
$updateForm->getElement('type_id')->addMultiOption('', '- Not Selected -');
$updateForm->getElement('type_id')->addMultiOptions($selectData);
```

This allows the value NULL to be written to a MySQL Integer field with NULL Allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Zend_Filter_Null to this field:

```
$updateForm->getElement('type_id')->addFilter(new Zend_Filter_Null());
```

Then just retrieve data from this form using $updateForm->getValues() and the empty strings will be replaced by null values.